# Is splitting the database result in a faster query time?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have a database with 100k users in it, I want to search for a name, would it be faster to split the database by each letter in the alphabet, this way I can check what is being searched for and direct the search to a smaller database. What do you guys think.

Comment: I would index the database. So you can browse the database faster

Comment: `index` the database, I wouldn't split it up as you may want to search for part of a username at some point.

Comment: I didn't make the database yet, and ofc it will be indexed, just wondering would splitting result in a faster query time.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253140/how-do-i-efficiently-search-a-potentially-large-database) and [this](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?977906-How-to-search-large-database)

Comment: 100k rows in a table is not a lot of data. As previously mentioned, you should index the database.

Comment: Index field with names, mysql will search much faster. Or use any other search engines like sphinx or elastic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely not.  Databases are designed for a large amount of data, and 100k rows is not a large amount of data.

For what you want to do, an index on the column you are searching for is probably quite sufficient.  If you actually did have tens of millions of rows (or more), you would start to think about partitioning strategies as well.

And, if you were to break of the data, doing it by only the first letter would be a very poor choice of partitioning key.  The resulting 26 groups would be very disproportionate in size.

The place to start learning about indexes and partitioning is the MySQL documentation, although even basic instruction on databases usually explains something about indexes.